# I use `ps -ef` find a `mysqld` progress, but how can I know which conf file it using?

Tags: centos, mysql

I use `ps -ef` find a `mysqld` progress, but how can I know which conf file it using?

```
[root@controller data]# ps -ef | grep mysql
mysql     8901     1  0 15:15 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/mysqld
root      8974   327  0 15:16 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto mysql
```

Comment: Due to cascaded loading of the configuration files, this might not be possible: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2482234/6216002

Comment: not only mysql, there are many progress.

Comment: As far as I know, a generic approach will not work here. Some applications have their configuration file specified on the command line, some don't. Some applications may not even have a configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

If you get the content of file `/proc/8901/cmdline` you will see what is the command line for this process and where is the config file. Here 8901 is the PID of your process. You can use also

```
ps -efl|grep mysql
```

to get long listing and in most of the case you will get entire command line

Also you can check for config file on usual places:

```
/etc/my.cnf
/etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

Comment: there is nothing in `/proc/my PID/cmdline`.

Comment: @244boy, please check the second idea. And also edited answer

Comment: Thanks, brother, I know my progress use the `/etc/my.cnf`, but I want to know whether there is a command for finding the using config file.

Comment: have you try to get the content of `cmdline`with `cat /proc/my PID/cmdline`?

Comment: there is nothing there.

Comment: @244boy, have you check with `ps -efl|grep mysql`

Comment: same to  ps -ef |grep mysql

Answer (score 0):

Try with `strace -fe trace=open mysql`; that will show you all the files used for that process, including the conf file; strace is not installed by default in most of the systems but you can install it without problems from the repositories.